# HTTP Request random JSON placement

Tags: json, http, post, powerapps

I came across HTTP requests on PowerApps Web API [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/create-entity-web-api#create-related-entity-records-in-one-operation). I understand the parameters here until the JSON at the bottom. To which HTTP request parameter does the JSON belong to?

```
POST[OrganizationURI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts$select=name&$expand=primarycontactid($select=fullname),Account_Tasks($select=subject) HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Accept: application/json
Prefer: return=representation

{
    "name": "Sample Account",
    "primarycontactid@odata.bind": "/contacts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001)",
    "Account_Tasks@odata.bind": [
        "/tasks(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002)",
        "/tasks(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003)"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that is just the body of the HTTP request. For example, if using Postman, put the JSON into the Body tab and set it as raw text.

[image]